# Schema.org markup json-ld for product and types of product

Tags: json, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Does the below code consists of two structured data or one? Can I write the code using schema type "Product Group" and "hasVariant" because "SS wire rope", "PVC Coated wire rope" and the others are types of wire rope. Is my code right or wrong? Can it be applied on a webpage.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Wire Rope"
},
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Stainless Steel SS wire rope",
                "image": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/ss-wire-rope.jpg",
                "description": "The SS wire rope is a strong and flexible cable made of stainless steel wires twisted together, commonly used for various applications such as lifting, rigging, and suspension due to its durability and resistance to corrosion.",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "16"
                },
                "review": [
                    {
                        "@type": "Review",
                        "author": "Parth Parmar",
                        "datePublished": "2021-05-08",
                        "reviewBody": "The Stainless Steel SS wire ropes are strong and durable. Will recommend to others",
                        "name": "Will Recommend",
                        "reviewRating": {
                            "@type": "Rating",
                            "bestRating": "5",
                            "ratingValue": "4",
                            "worstRating": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Review",
                        "author": "Prashant Naik",
                        "datePublished": "2022-09-01",
                        "reviewBody": "Great Product from Svibo Industries, almost perfect! 4.5 stars.",
                        "name": "Good Service",
                        "reviewRating": {
                            "@type": "Rating",
                            "bestRating": "5",
                            "ratingValue": "4.5",
                            "worstRating": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item": {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "PVC Coated wire rope",
                "image": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/pr-203.png",
                "description": "PVC coated wire rope is a type of cable consisting of stainless steel wires encased in a protective PVC (polyvinyl chloride) coating. This coating provides additional resistance to corrosion, abrasion, and weathering, making it suitable for outdoor and marine applications.",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.7",
                    "reviewCount": "21"
                },
                "review": [
                    {
                        "@type": "Review",
                        "author": "Durgesh Kulkarni",
                        "datePublished": "2023-09-18",
                        "reviewBody": "The plastic used is of top quality.",
                        "name": "High quality plastic",
                        "reviewRating": {
                            "@type": "Rating",
                            "bestRating": "5",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "worstRating": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Review",
                        "author": "Saurabh Sinha",
                        "datePublished": "2022-05-17",
                        "reviewBody": "You can forget corrosion",
                        "name": "Prevents corrosion well",
                        "reviewRating": {
                            "@type": "Rating",
                            "bestRating": "5",
                            "ratingValue": "4.6",
                            "worstRating": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 3,
            "item": {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Galvanized wire rope",
                "image": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/galvanized-wire-rope-500x500-1.png",
                "description": "Galvanized wire rope is a cable made of steel wires that are coated with a layer of zinc through the process of galvanization.",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.7",
                    "reviewCount": "8"
                },
                "review": [
                    {
                        "@type": "Review",
                        "author": "Roshan Karkera",
                        "datePublished": "2018-06-12",
                        "reviewBody": "Gets the job done.",
                        "name": "Gets the job done",
                        "reviewRating": {
                            "@type": "Rating",
                            "bestRating": "5",
                            "ratingValue": "4.6",
                            "worstRating": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Review",
                        "author": "Gaurav Tiwari",
                        "datePublished": "2021-02-18",
                        "reviewBody": "Nice product",
                        "name": "Nice",
                        "reviewRating": {
                            "@type": "Rating",
                            "bestRating": "5",
                            "ratingValue": "4.8",
                            "worstRating": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 4,
            "item": {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "Ungalvanized wire rope ",
                "image": "https://sviboindustries.in/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/black-steel-wire-rope-500x500-1.jpg",
                "description": "Ungalvanized wire rope is a cable made of steel wires without a protective zinc coating.",
                "aggregateRating": {
                    "@type": "AggregateRating",
                    "ratingValue": "4.9",
                    "reviewCount": "15"
                },
                "review": [
                    {
                        "@type": "Review",
                        "author": "Asif Khan",
                        "datePublished": "2018-04-16",
                        "reviewBody": "Used it for my construction company",
                        "name": "Great for indoor use",
                        "reviewRating": {
                            "@type": "Rating",
                            "bestRating": "5",
                            "ratingValue": "4.9",
                            "worstRating": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "Review",
                        "author": "Saurabh Sinha",
                        "datePublished": "2022-01-27",
                        "reviewBody": "Great!",
                        "name": "Great product",
                        "reviewRating": {
                            "@type": "Rating",
                            "bestRating": "5",
                            "ratingValue": "4.8",
                            "worstRating": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

I am trying to write a schema markup in JSON-LD format for the product "Wire Rope".The Stainless Steel Wire Rope,Galvanized Wire Rope and Ungalvanized Wire Rope are types of wire rope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any structured data consumer that officially supports the idea of product variants.

Google and Schema.org have been talking about how best to support it, but nothing solid yet.

There's a long conversation on it in the Schema.org github repository:

https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1797

If we take your current code and put it in the Google Rich Result Tester, you will see that Google is ignoring all but your first product.

At this time, I would suggest you only add one Product per page because that's what the consumers like Google currently support.